# System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The Authority/Host could not be parsed

Tags: asp.net, exception, uri

`Uri uri = new Uri(siteURL);`

Where `siteURL="https://abcdev.sharepoint.com/sites/TestDuplicate";`

I am getting the Exception:

> System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The Authority/Host could not be parsed

Comment: That by itself should be OK. There must be some other code causing the error.

Comment: This is the line where i get the exception.

Answer (score 0):

The code above looks correct. Even in the run time in Immediate window it does work well.
Are you sure you don't do any operations on strings? I have had similar error when my host was improperly formatted:

**var requestString = string.Join('/', urlParts).Replace("//", "/");**

What it did, was to replace **http://** with **http:/** and this caused an exception.